# No way to add instagram in AddToAny Plugin?

Tags: plugins

I’m looking to add Instagram to my follow buttons, and on the settings pages it tells me:

You can setup Instagram, YouTube, Snapchat, and other buttons in an AddToAny Follow widget.

Add the “AddToAny Follow” widget in Customize or Widgets.

But in the AddToAny Follow Widget i’ve got linkedin, twitter and facebook. No trace of instagram, that is what I’m trying to add. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5QbD.jpg)

What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 1):

From reviewing the documentation it looks like Instagram isn't supported directly.

However, AddToAny supports custom services. Just take a look at the product documentation '[Custom Services - WordPress](https://www.addtoany.com/buttons/customize/wordpress/add_services)'

Answer (score 1):

In your functions.php, you can add these lines:

```
/*  AddToAny Instagram */
function addtoany_add_share_services( $services ) {
    $services['example_share_service'] = array(
        'name'        => 'Instagram',
        'icon_url'    => site_url('/wp-content/plugins/add-to-any/icons/instagram.svg'),
        'icon_width'  => 40,
        'icon_height' => 40,
        'href'        => 'https://www.instagram.com/',
    );
    return $services;
}
add_filter( 'A2A_SHARE_SAVE_services', 'addtoany_add_share_services', 10, 1 );
```

You will then find it in the AddToAny settings.